# vuetify progress-linear component does not show progress as expected

Tags: vuetify.js

I am working on a dashboard project where I want to present several widgets on the dashboard. one of these is to show the admins a visualisation of their active/idle devices and since the whole project is vuetify based, I am trying to do this with v-progress-linear component. But for some reason it doesn't show the progress properly even if I am not changing the value for the bar. Below is my code and a screen shot of the result. I couldn't find any solution to this online so I assume I am missing something very basic about the component's usage or the grid layout that it is wrapped by.

Any help would be appreciated... 
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i97mx.png)

```html
<template>
<v-container fluid class="grey lighten-5">
    <v-card outlined flat class="mx-auto" align="center">
        <v-icon large class="mt-5 mb-1">mdi-developer-board</v-icon>
        <v-card-title class="justify-center pt-1 display-2 font-weight-black" > {{totalDevices}} </v-card-title>
        <v-card-subtitle class="justify-center">Total no of Devices</v-card-subtitle>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-row >
            <v-col>
                <v-card flat>
                <span class="caption" >Active: </span>
                <span class="subtitle-2" >{{totalActive}}</span>
                <v-progress-linear style="margin : 0 auto ;" class="mt-3" determinate color="#3cd1c2" :value="calcProgressValue('active')" ></v-progress-linear>
                </v-card >
            </v-col>
            <v-divider vertical></v-divider>
            <v-col class="d-flex justify-center">
                <v-card flat>
                    <span class="caption">Idle: </span>
                    <span class="subtitle-2 align-right" >{{totalIdle}}</span>
                    <v-progress-linear style="margin : 0 auto ;" class="mt-3 text-xs-center" determinate color="#ffaa2c" :value="calcProgressValue('idle')" ></v-progress-linear>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
        </v-card>
</v-container>
</template>
```

Comment: What should the progress-bar really looks like?

Comment: the end goal is to have two separate bars aligned centrally in each column/card showing the relative amount of active and idle devices as a progress bar (where the value of each bar is calculated as the relative part of the fleet) that starts the progress from the left side. the methods i am using above for calculations work, but even if i leave these out and use hard-coded values, the progress bars are not presented correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `:value="calcProgressValue('active')"` just do `:value="totalActive"` which seems to be a variable or computed value